# Rank columns column-wise with rule

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, tidyverse

This question is a variation of this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45562700/rank-values-column-wise), however I'm not sure why I'm not getting the correct result.

My data:

```
dput(temp)
structure(list(MB = c("4001826", "4007824", "4007948", "4010876", 
"4015215"), Margin = c(900, 30733.0616, 15525, 2689.05865, 4340
), T1 = c(300, 11296.491, 38810, 1379.44, 870), T2 = c(360, 12706.491, 
46404, 1466.44, 1050), T3 = c(390, 13430.491, 49781, 1574.44, 
1141), T4 = c(420, 15146.491, 55274, 1720.44, 1230), T5 = c(900, 
30972.2633, 109829.852, 1807.44, 2670), T6 = c(960, 41017.3059, 
119443.9056, 2718.2, 2850), T7 = c(1020, 42079.3059, 128232.9056, 
2907.2, 3020), T8 = c(1200, 44461.3059, 151137.9056, 3314.2, 
3540), T9 = c(1500, 46936.3059, 180746.9056, 3746.2, 4400), T10 = c(1800, 
48246.3059, 199116.9056, 3746.2, 5260), T11 = c(1530, 35279.3059, 
144154.9056, 2748.2, 4415), T12 = c(1500, 33350.3059, 138818.9056, 
2881.2, 4330), T13 = c(1500, 34719.3059, 140508.9056, 2893.2, 
4330), T14 = c(1800, 58092.3059, 205687.9056, 2463.2, 5220), 
    T15 = c(390, 35438.0846, 68364.8492, 2987.1718, 1172), T16 = c(390, 
    32038.0139, 64451.0925, 2655.5102, 1162), T17 = c(390, 30219.2716, 
    67860.3977, 2462.239, 1162), T18 = c(608.397, 49543.5875, 
    113689.9478, 3643.7126, 1872), T19 = c(660, 34080.84615, 
    85176.3018, 2284.9598, 1923)), .Names = c("MB", "Margin", 
"T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T7", "T8", "T9", "T10", 
"T11", "T12", "T13", "T14", "T15", "T16", "T17", "T18", "T19"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I want to do, is find a T-group which has the the **closest value (smaller or equal) to margin**. So my rule is:

- min(T-Value <= Margin)

I have made this attempt:

```
temp <- gather(temp, Closest_column, val, T1:T19) %>% 
  group_by(MB) %>% 
  slice(max(which(val <= Margin)[1]))
```

But two wierd things happen. First, the temp variable returns 4 rows, rather than 5. And second, the result is incorrect:

```
head(temp)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   MB [4]
       MB    Margin Closest_column      val
    <chr>     <dbl>          <chr>    <dbl>
1 4001826   900.000             T1   300.00
2 4007824 30733.062             T1 11296.49
3 4010876  2689.059             T1  1379.44
4 4015215  4340.000             T1   870.00
```

For **4001826**, the assigned closest column is T1, but it should be T5 which is equal in value (Margin = 900.00, T5 = 900.00).

For **4007824** it should be T17, which is the least smallest from Margin (Margin = 30733.062 , T17 = 30219.27).

Any clue where I'm getting it wrong?

Comment: It is only because there is a case where for the group it is not tru for any of the elements.  In that case, what do you want as output.  Also, regarding the other queries, we are only checking `which` are the values that are less than the other one and then getting the maximum of the index and not the value.  So may need `gather(temp, Closest_column, val, T1:T19) %>%  group_by(MB)  %>% slice(which.min(abs(val - Margin)))`

Comment: The third row is a problem: `test <- temp %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(lessthanistrue = any(c(T1:T19) <= Margin))`

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code a little bit. The rule is changed as follows:

1. Filter records that `val` is smaller than or equal to `Margin`.
2. Rank by the absolute difference between Margin and each `T` column.
3. If there is a tie, select the `T` column with smaller column number.

Here is the code. `temp2` is the final output.

```
temp2 <- temp %>%
  gather(Col, val, T1:T19) %>% 
  # Filter those records with val smaller than or equal to Margin
  filter(val <= Margin) %>%
  # Calculate the absolute difference between Margin and val
  mutate(Diff = abs(val - Margin)) %>%
  # Create factor for the Closest_column
  mutate(Col = factor(Col, levels = paste0("T", 1:(ncol(temp) - 2)))) %>%
  # Sort by MB, Diff, then Col
  arrange(MB, Diff, Col) %>%
  group_by(MB) %>% 
  slice(1) %>%
  rename(Closest_column = Col)
temp2
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   MB [4]
       MB    Margin Closest_column      val      Diff
    <chr>     <dbl>         <fctr>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 4001826   900.000             T5   900.00   0.00000
2 4007824 30733.062            T17 30219.27 513.79000
3 4010876  2689.059            T16  2655.51  33.54845
4 4015215  4340.000            T12  4330.00  10.00000
```